# How to forward stateful bean reference in servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets, ejb

I have a stateful bean and its been invoked in servlet.

I need to keep the reference across 5 servlets and JSP's. How to acheive that.

Initially, request from JSP to servlet, and request will be forwarded to next JSP, from the 2nd JSP how to retrieve the reference of same bean in next servlet.

Hope My question is clear.

No Session must be used. How to keep forwarding?

**Requirement:**

Get form filled in JSP1 and forward to servlet.

invoke the stateful bean in servlet and forward to JSP2.

get the form filled in JSP2 (remaining part of form) and forward to servlet and operate on same stateful bean.

Now, i need the same bean to invoke the other methods, How can I keep the reference of that stateful bean across servlet and JSP?

Can I use request for keep forwarding to all this JSP and servlets.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: *Can I use request for keep forwarding to all this JSP and servlets?* Yes you can. *How to keep forwarding?* just make sure to not destroy your stateful EJB while using it.

Comment: How to keep forwarding? just make sure to not destroy your stateful EJB while using it. **Can you please elaborate this**